# Let mySQL do the work or process it in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I use php to upload images and create multiple clones of the same image using a suffix, like so

```
image154547457_thumb.jpg
image154547457_small.jpg
image154547457_400x500.jpg
image154547457_800x1000.jpg
image154547457_100x125.jpg
image154547457_retina.jpg
...
```

I use the last 2 characters of the filename to store the clone images in the filesystem, so i don't end up with one big directory, like so

```
/gallery/files/7/5
```

I store a reference to the image in a mySQL table like so

```
image (image_id, caption, filedir, filename, fileext)


image  caption filedir filename         filext
------------------------------------------------------------
1      ....    7/5/    image154547457   jpg
```

Then, i retrieve the images that i need for my project, like so

```
SELECT i.image_id, i.caption, CONCAT(i.filedir, i.filename, '_thumb', '.', fileext) thumb, CONCAT(i.filedir, i.filename, '_retina', '.', fileext) retina, CONCAT(i.filedir, i.filename, '_800x1000', '.', fileext) _800
FROM image i
WHERE i.image_id = 1
```

This is where i need advice from the experts.

I can also have just the filename in mySQL, like so

```
image   caption  filename
-----------------------------------
1       ....     image154547457.jpg
```

retrieve it like so

```
SELECT i.image_id, i.caption, i.filename
FROM image i
WHERE i.image_id = 1
```

and use PHP to do the rest of the process, like so

```
$filename = substr($filename, 0 , strrpos($filename, ".")); 
$filedir = substr($filename, -1) . '/' . substr($filename, -2, 1) . '/';
$filext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, ".") + 1);

thumb = $filedir . $filename . '_thumb' . '.' . fileext;
retina = $filedir . $filename . '_retina' . '.' . fileext;
_800 = $filedir . $filename . '_800x1000' . '.' . fileext;
```

Let's say that im retrieving 100 images per page.

Which is more expensive and/or the better approach?
Retrieve the info directly from MYSQL (2 extra columns) or use PHP to process it (no need for 'filedir' and 'fileext' columns in mysql table) ?

I did some research here, and i wasn't able to find an answer to this logical question.

Comment: have you done some simple benchmark tests to see which performs better?

Comment: This is micro-optimization, which is usually not worth worrying about. Simple string concatenation is a very minor amount of work. Measure it if you want, but I expect the difference will hardly be detectable.

Comment: IMHO The logic of deciding which image to show is part of the 'view' logic, or how you generate the HTML.  All the database should be concerned with is the name of the base image.  As you only store the base image name in the database then let it just return that and leave it to how you generate the end page to add any suffix on.

Comment: If it is efficiency you're after then why not just store the whole file path in the database? Probably because it is inflexible. I would try to only store the identity of the image in the database and, just like Nigel Ren says, let a separate piece of PHP code worry about where it is stored. This might not be as efficient, but in the long run it allows you to change the way images are stored without having to update the database.